# Looking for a scalable way to get all datatypes of _id in a mongodb collection without having to make an expensive aggregation call?

Tags: mongodb, parallel-processing, mongodb-query

My use case is to get all datatype of _id present in a collection. I use these _id types in further downstream processes. This is primarily required as [MongoDB doesn't itself return all datatypes with a $gte/$lte](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/method/db.collection.find/#type-bracketing) operation and only returns the values of the datatype mentioned. I'd need the datatypes of _id to achieve the necessary parallelizations. Currently, I'm using a DB aggregation call to the collection:

```
db.collection.aggregate({ $group : { _id : {$type:"$_id"}} } )
```

However, this is an extremely expensive call especially when the size of the collection is in the billions. I was hoping that since there is no internal comparator in MongoDB to distinguish between, say an objectID and a numeric type, I should be able to get the datatypes of _id present in some metadata ideally. Is there any such way to get this information or perhaps a faster way to get all datatypes of _id in a collection?

Comment: There is no right way to achieve this by aggregation query, you have to use other approaches like storing these unique datatypes in a separate collection, you have to manage that types if new entries come into your main collection. and you can reduce that approach by storing those datatypes in memory whatever backend language you are using, you can check if the datatype id is new then you can insert them in your new datatype collection.

Answer (score -1):

You can hint the queryPlanner to use the _id index in the aggregation query as follow:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
    {$group:{
             _id:{$type:"$_id"}
            }
     }
   ],
     {
       hint:"_id_"
     }
   )
```